# Are accident reviews comprehensive enough?

Tags: aircraft-design, accident-investigation

There is lots of speculation on accident causes. How complete is the FAA / NTSB analysis of accidents in terms of detailed responses from the manufacturer and expected corrective actions that will be taken to lower the chances for a repeat?

Are actions addressed in terms of management, design, quality control and customer actions that contribute to the risk? Is NTSB and manufacturer analysis critiqued by independent reviewers for completeness?

Comment: What makes you think this sort of thing doesn't happen?  (FWIW, it is the NTSB that investigates accidents.)

Comment: Seems like "comprehensive *enough*" is only answerable with opinions (although the existing answer makes the strong case that for any reasonable opinion, the answer would be "yes").

Comment: Is it an chicken-egg problem? FAA publishes accident reviews to make aware other agents about dangers and corrective actions, so it cannot include responses on that. On other reports (annual reports and specific report published less often) you may get data about effect of the published report.

Comment: I wonder what aircraft accident investigation reports you've read that do _not_ include all these things.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, they are very comprehensive.

As officially stated, [reports do provide](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Pages/Reports.aspx) details about the accident, analysis of the factual data, conclusions and the probable cause of the accident, and the related safety recommendations.

Commercial aircraft accident investigations are significantly more thorough than they are for road vehicles, buildings, industrial plants, consumer products, and just about anything else. Their conclusions are also acted upon swiftly and firmly, which is how an inherently challenging activity was turned into the safest mode of transportation on a per-mile basis.

For [class 1 investigations](https://www.ntsb.gov/about/organization/AS/Pages/aviation-classification.aspx) (airliner accidents that make the news are usually class 1), the report is typically between 200 and 400 pages, including diagrams, illustrations, context, and plain language explanations. In most countries, these reports are very well-written, following a similar structure. Most of these reports are easily readable by the general public, requiring only a modicum of knowledge of basic engineering or aeronautical terms.

Here are some select reports:

- Famous [TWA 800](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/accidentreports/reports/aar0003.pdf) - 747 midair explosion
- [Ethiopian 737 MAX 8](https://bea.aero/fileadmin/user_upload/ET_302__B737-8MAX_ACCIDENT_FINAL_REPORT.pdf) - note it's foreign, but follows a similar template
- [JAL 123](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/JAL123_Acc_Report.pdf) - deadliest single aircraft crash, 747, Japan (hard to read, see below for FAA version)
- [USA 1549](https://www.atsb.gov.au/sites/default/files/media/4173625/ao-2010-089_final.pdf) - A320 on the Hudson, basis for the Sully movie
- [Qantas Flight 32](https://www.atsb.gov.au/sites/default/files/media/4173625/ao-2010-089_final.pdf) - engine failure, A380, very well-illustrated

Note that they are produced by the NTSB, or by other nations' safety agencies - typically, the operating country makes the final report. However, different national agencies, including always that where the accident occurred, that where the aircraft was designed or built, the airline's flag country, and sometimes others, collaborate on producing it.

The process is simpler for private flights. If it's a [Piper crash-landing](https://data.ntsb.gov/carol-repgen/api/Aviation/ReportMain/GenerateNewestReport/193597/pdf), or [a seaplane clipping a motorboat](https://data.ntsb.gov/carol-repgen/api/Aviation/ReportMain/GenerateNewestReport/193427/pdf), that's a class 4; they make a prelim, take a month to do the paperwork, and release a 4 to 10 page long report. If it's an airliner accident, the investigation takes as long as it takes to find the proximate cause and propose a solution. If they have to reassemble the airplane from small pieces, they do it; [the longest investigation took almost 5 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USAir_Flight_427) (report on [USA 427](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAR9901.pdf)). It doesn't stop until it's done.

The acceptance rate and the speed of implementations for air safety recommendations are much higher than in other industries. About 85% of class 1 investigations result in changes in practices or retrofits within a year. Most marine, rail, road and building safety improvements only apply to new designs, with the exception of specific critical faults.

All information of interest to the general public is included in the Final Report. I strongly recommend reading at least TWA and Qantas reports if you want to get a sense of how they're done and what they contain.

If you want even more information, look through the dockets, which at least in the US are also made public. In a class 1 investigation, it can total thousands of pages, as for the [TWA 800 investigation](https://data.ntsb.gov/Docket/?NTSBNumber=DCA96MA070). That's literally everything, including investigation reports into rejected versions - e.g. a [24-page report](https://data.ntsb.gov/Docket/Document/docBLOB?ID=40394702&FileExtension=.PDF&FileName=TWA%20Flight%20800%20Missile%20Impact%20Analysis-Redacted.PDF) on the missile impact hypothesis. Some of these papers require engineering knowledge to understand.

The FAA also maintain a page with [even shorter summaries](https://www.faa.gov/lessonslearned/transportairplane/accidents/transport-airplane-lessons-learned-library) for most influential accidents. It's particularly useful for accidents from non-English-speaking countries, where different writing culture can make official translations hard to digest. FAA's [JAL 123 summary](https://www.faa.gov/lessons_learned/transport_airplane/accidents/JA8119) is much easier to read than the Japanese version above.

Comment: Therac, great call. A long time ago, I took an Accident Investigation & Analysis course taught by one of the TWA 800 investigators. It was one of the best classes I’ve taken.

Comment: I'd add [this link](https://www.faa.gov/lessonslearned/transportairplane/accidents/transport-airplane-lessons-learned-library) to your answer which is an FAA site explaining in a simple but thorough way the "most significant" incidents happened in the past. Even the JAL123 is explained better than the official report 

Comment: @sophit Thanks, added. I think it's indeed a better starting point for someone uninvolved with aviation; somewhere between the wiki and the official report.

Answer (score 4):

To focus on the safety recommendations part of your question:

As mentioned in [Therac's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/102405), the FAA is not the primary agency investigating aviation accidents. The NTSB is the US agency responsible for investigations. This provides independence between the investigation and the regulation, but it also means they have no authority to change anything and can only issue recommendations.

Especially for more serious incidents, the thorough NTSB reports will often contain a section with recommendations to the FAA or other relevant bodies. The scope of the recommendations is not limited to just the specific incident being investigated but may include additional findings that happen to come up in the course of the investigation. These recommendations are [separately tracked](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/Pages/safety-recommendations.aspx) and the NTSB notes whether there is an acceptable response that addresses the concern. In 2022, the NTSB closed 269 previous recommendations as having acceptable responses, and 34 as having unacceptable responses.

Here is a chart of the recipients of all recommendations since the NTSB was created in 1967. This includes all modes of transportation they investigate for; aviation comprises 38% of these recommendations.

[image: Chart of all NTSB safety recommendations by recipient]
<sub>Source: [NTSB](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/Pages/safety-recommendations.aspx)</sub>